# Do best practices eliminate the need for a CSRF token when writing an API server?

Tags: csrf, same-origin-policy, cors

I realize that OWASP recommends CSRF tokens but I rarely see them used with public standalone HTTP APIs. This would seem to indicate that they're not always necessary.

To make this a little more concrete, I would envision the following scenario:

- The API server serves a limited number of frontends with an explicit CORS whitelist.
- HTTP method semantics are followed religiously (no writes in GET).
- All routes require authentication.
- All POST routes require a request body[1].
- All routes that take a request body require a JSON content-type header.
- Cookies are httpOnly but not sameSite.

Based on my understanding of SOP setting a JSON content-type header on requests should trigger a preflight request which would fail for untrusted origins. If all POST routes require a JSON content-type header, that should then mean they'll always fail the preflight, leaving only GET requests.

So this would not mitigate CSRF attacks against GET routes but as these can't be used for exfiltration (as SOP prevents the response from being read) and the GET routes should not cause any data modification, guarding these requests with CSRF tokens would not appear to make a practical difference.

Given how viciously some people defend CSRF tokens, I can't shake the feeling I'm overlooking an obvious problem here. I realize redundant protections may be valuable in their own right, but what I'm trying to understand is whether in the scenario described the CSRF token would really be redundant or not.

---

[1]: I realise this might be a practical limitation of this approach as in some real-world APIs there are legitimate POST routes that don't take a request body or there may be routes that need to take a content-type like form-data that won't trigger a preflight.

Comment: I think the answer may be in my footnote: the reason people advocate for CSRF tokens is not that the entire server is vulnerable to CSRF but that it's easy to create routes which are. A POST route that doesn't take a request body or only form-data or url-encoded data and no additional headers would be vulnerable to CSRF and it's easy to miss that if you're not actively mitigating CSRF already.

Comment: Or if you accidentally perform a state change on a GET request.  Indeed, all these things are easy to do on accident.

Comment: Although I would add to that comment of yours and expand upon what is different about CSRF.  None of your above mitigation steps are specific to preventing CSRF, which is one of the reasons why it is easy to accidentally leave one out.  Someone could make a state changing route that doesn't require application/json, run into trouble testing it because of that requirement and very correctly wonder, "Why should I require application/json when I don't actually need application/json?".  As a result they remove it and break the security without realizing it.

Comment: Which is just the long way of saying: it's always best for things to have one and only one purpose.  If something has two purposes (announce the content type AND prevent against CSRF) it might be easily removed by accident, leaving a vulnerability.  A CSRF token has one, and only one purpose: to stop CSRF attacks.  That makes it harder for it to be removed without understanding the repercussions.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the point of CSRF tokens isn't that without them your application is necessarily vulnerable to CSRF but that if you do slip up and make a part of your application vulnerable to CSRF, the CSRF token prevents that from becoming an actual vulnerability that could be exploited? IOW it's not just about protecting the code you've already written but more about preventing future changes from introducing vulnerabilities, too?

Comment: IMHO you're missing SameSite in your list: https://caniuse.com/#feat=same-site-cookie-attribute. Chrome will default this to `lax` in future which will be -- once adopted by other browsers -- the coffin nail for CSRF: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592

Comment: csrf was over-rated 10 years ago in terms of concern / (actual attacks). Devs that excused away https bragged about adding csrf protection to benign site searches...

Comment: @eckes If the API is meant to be used cross-site (whether that's one of the OP's requirement is unclear, though) and if the API uses cookies for session management, then the session-identifying cookie cannot be same-site or the API won't work.